# threeparttablex with regular table

Tags: tables, threeparttable, threeparttablex

Is there a way to use threeparttablex with a regular table (`tabular` environmnent)?
I like the additional features it provides.

I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltxtable,threeparttablex,booktabs}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
   \begin{table}
           \centering
   \begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}
    \item[1] a very long text and a very long text and a very long text
    \end{TableNotes}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
      \toprule
      AAAA\tnote{a} & XXXXXXXX & BBBB\\
      BBBB\tnote{a} & XXXXXXXX & CCCC\\
      \bottomrule\\
      \insertTableNotes
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A tabular.}
  \end{ThreePartTable}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

and got

[image: The result where the notes are too narrow]

I needed to include `ltxtable`, otherwise I get an error.

With something like `\renewcommand\TPTminimum{\textwidth}`,
I could change the width of the notes manually, but is there an automated way?

Comment: You can use the additional features of **threeparttablex** but not like that. You need to use the regular `threeparttable` environment, but you can tell **threeparttablex** that you want it to supercharge the regular environment and not just define the one for `longtable`s. The documentation explains this and includes examples.

Comment: Since you don't say *which* additional features you want and since your example doesn't make that clear, there isn't much point in posting an answer as it may be that you want some feature not supported and I wouldn't anyway know what to demonstrate. But remember that a `longtable` ***is not a float*** whereas a `table` is. So obviously some things are going to be different and some of what you show (e.g. location of `\caption`) is a function of `longtable` rather than `ThreePartTable`, I think.

Comment: You might like the ctable package